# Apollo GraphQL Lambda Handler Cannot read property 'method' of undefined when accessing http endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, apollo-server

My Code,

index.js
........................

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler, handlers, middleware } from '@as-integrations/aws-lambda';

const typeDefs = `#graphql
  type Query {
    hello: String!
  }
`;


const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'world',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});


const graphqlHandler = startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler(
  server,
  handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventV2RequestHandler(),
  {
    middleware: [
      async (event) => {
        console.log('###? received event=' + JSON.stringify(event))
      }
    ]
}
);


export { graphqlHandler as handler  }
```

serverless.yml
........................

```
service: apollo-lambda
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  httpApi:
    cors: true
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: src/server.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /cep
          method: POST
      - httpApi:
          path: /cep
          method: GET
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

package.json
.........................

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.9.5",
    "@as-integrations/aws-lambda": "^3.1.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
    "serverless-offline": "^13.2.0"
  }
```

After deploying to AWS Lambda and hitting the endpoint throwing below error. Code is packaged as .zip file and manually deployed to Lambda through AWS Console.

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'method')`

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found es6 exports to be touchy with serverless. Try:

```
exports.handler = graphqlHandler
```

in `index.js`